# Получить все объекты из Set по key в foreach

Tags: java, foreach, map

Работаю с библиотекой itext и хочу создать отчет. Нужно по магазину вытащить все его продукты. Храню в Map<String, Set>, где string -> имя магазина, а Set -> хранит список продуктов в виде объектов. По циклу я пытаюсь засунуть в таблицу itext из 5 столбцов:
Shop, Product,Price , Count, Total. В итоге код отрабатывает, но я получаю лишь 1 запись продукта (а их больше). Я знаю что ошибка в цикле по перебору по ключу, не могу понять как исправить, буду рад любой критике. (В виду отсутствия возможности доступа к коду, прикрепляю скрин)

[image]

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос текстом, а не скриншотом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы проходитесь по стриму `value.stream()`, и возвращаете из него `.findFirst()` ?

Comment: Верно подмечено, тут и есть ошибка, я думаю необходимо заменить map на foreach и в него поместить строку с добавлением ключа

Comment: @Danzxz, да, вам необходимо использовать `foreach`